# Running batch file multiple times without having to press ENTER key

Tags: batch-file

Hi I would like to run my batch file several times (say, 10000 times). Now after each run the windows command asks me to press "Enter key" which makes my life difficult. Is there any way I can run my batch file 10000 times without having to press "Enter key"? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Add your script please

Comment: How do we know? You haven't shown your batch file so we can see why it's asking you to press Enter.

Comment: Edit the batch file and remark out or remove the `pause` command.  Then on a command line, to run the script 1000 times, do `for /L %I in (1,1,1000) do scriptname.bat`

Comment: You getting down-vote because you ask for help on a problem of code that we do not see the consistency. On after you say, it would work in an almost infinite loop. You, who do not even know the command `PAUSE` Do you know at least if your script is not destructors in the computer in which it runs?

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should remove the PAUSE from the end of your script. But if you don't want to modify the script, then you can effectively disable the pause by redirecting stdin to nul.

You can use the FOR /L loop to iterate 10000 times.

From the command prompt:

```
for /l %N in (1 1 10000) do <nul yourScript.bat
```

Using a batch script

```
@echo off
for /l %%N in (1 1 10000) do <nul call yourScript.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

- Write the batch file that doesn't query the user.
- Install unix tools and write it using a shell script.
- Use Command redirection eg.: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I am not familiar with that at all. Thanks for your response though.